# OOD: class hierarchy with method arguments forming another hierarchy

Tags: object-oriented

I'd like to find out how do you guys handle the following situation: you have a class hierarchy, call it H1, with some polymorphic method that is supposed to accept an argument which type forms hierarchy H2 in the following way: the higher the class is in H1, the higher H2 argument it accepts.

```
+-----------+           +-----------+
|     A     |           |     A'    |
|-----------+           +-----------+
|method(A') |                 ^
+-----------+                 |
      ^                 +-----------+ 
      |                 |     B'    |
+-----------+           +-----------+
|     B     |                 ^
|-----------+                 |
|method(B') |           +-----------+ 
+-----------+           |     C'    |
      ^                 +-----------+
      |
+-----------+
|     C     |
|-----------+
|method(C') |
+-----------+
```

Before writing any code I mention that I have two protocol classes with methods `check` that have much in common, but request parameters are specific for concrete arguments -- transactions.
The language is scala, but the problem is language-agnostic.
At the first glance it should look like that:

```
trait BaseMerchantProtocol
{
  def check(transaction: BaseTransaction) = {
    // some common code...
    println(requestParams(transaction))
    // ...and here as well
  }

  protected def requestParams(transaction: BaseTransaction)
}

class SmsCommerceMerchantProtocol extends BaseMerchantProtocol
{
  override protected def requestParams(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for SmsCommerceTransaction class")
  }
}

class TelepayMerchantProtocol extends BaseMerchantProtocol
{
  override protected def requestParams(transaction: TelepayTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for TelepayTransaction class")
  }
}
```

But of course it does not compile as Liskov substitution principle is violated.

Let's try this one:

```
trait IMerchantProtocol {
  def check(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction)
  def check(transaction: TelepayTransaction)
}

class MerchantProtocol extends IMerchantProtocol
{
  def check(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction) = {
    doCheck(transaction)
  }

  def check(transaction: TelepayTransaction) = {
    doCheck(transaction)
  }

  private def requestParams(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for SmsCommerceTransaction class")
  }

  private def requestParams(transaction: TelepayTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for TelepayTransaction class")
  }

  private def doCheck(transaction: BaseTransaction) = {
    // some common code...
    println(requestParams(transaction))
    // ...and here as well
  }
}
```

But that won't compile as well -- and with the same reason: `doCheck` accepts `BaseTransaction`, but `requestParams`s have more strict preconditions.

The only thing that I came up with and that works is the following:

```
class MerchantProtocol extends IMerchantProtocol
{
  def check(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction) = {
    doCheck(transaction, requestParams(transaction))
  }

  def check(transaction: TelepayTransaction) = {
    doCheck(transaction, requestParams(transaction))
  }

  private def requestParams(transaction: SmsCommerceTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for SmsCommerceTransaction class")
  }

  private def requestParams(transaction: TelepayTransaction) = {
    List("result specific for TelepayTransaction class")
  }

  private def doCheck(transaction: BaseTransaction, requestParams: List[String]) = {
    // some common code...
    println(requestParams)
    // ...and here as well
  }
}
```

But I don't like that all `check` methods belong to the same class.
How can I split them by classes?

Comment: What would happen if class D would derive from B and would accept D', which derives from B' and then : B = new D(); B.method(new C'()) ? While your idea might work with list hierarchy of classes, it stops making sense when you have tree hierarchy. I think you are approaching your problem from the wrong way.

Comment: Are those base (`A` and `A'`) and intermediate (`B` and `B'`) classes actually instantiated ever, or are they abstract, and only the most derived classes (`C` and `C'`) are instantiated?

Comment: @dbc All of them are concrete classes.

Comment: @Euphoric I wanted to outline a problem that I encounter quite often: some objects that (seem to) form a class hierarchy do something with (or with the help of) other objects that (seem to) form a class hierarchy as well. I.e., the more specific is the handler class, the more specific class it handles. I agree that I possibly approach the problem from the wrong way. But way is better?

Comment: @Zapadlo - Could a class instance of type A (`BaseMerchantProtocol`) be instantiated and actually process transactions of B' (`SmsCommerceTransaction`) and C' (`TelepayTransaction`) as well as A' (`BaseTransaction`)?

Comment: I believe this kind of "separation" is right against what OOP is about. OOP is about bundling data and operations that use that data. Separating those results in exactly the problem you are describing. I was actually thinking about possible solution to this some time back, but couldn't find any reasonable solution.

Comment: @dbc No, only `B` can process `B'`. Class `A` contains logic that is common for all its child classes, but nothing specific for some of its child classes. So I'm sorry for my previous comment -- any of them *possibly* can be abstract (but it just not my current case, that's why I told that all of them are concrete).

Comment: @Euphoric sorry for not answering your first comment right away.
If there was another child class `D` that would derive from `B`, it would never accept `C'` as argument -- it would accept `D'`.

Comment: Zapadlo, thats not how virtual methods and polymorphism work. method(B') accepts all classes that derive from B', be it C' or D'. Those are basics of OOP and I should not have to explain those in comments.

Comment: @Euphoric I know how polymorphism works. I indicated problems that arise when coming up with this class structure. I'm not defending it -- oppositely, I'm trying to find another, proper one.
The common problem is the following, again: some objects that (seem to) form a class hierarchy do something with (or with the help of) other objects that (seem to) form a class hierarchy as well. I.e., the more specific is the handler class, the more specific class it handles.

Comment: @Euphoric I guess you haven't seen the notification about my comment to your answer -- could you please take a look at it?

Comment: I think that two hierarchies, that mirror one another is not cause, it is an effect of some deeper cause. IMO it is usually effect of separating what should be one hierarchy across application layers. In that case, pure OOP doesn't have tools to handle that and you need to resign to using hacks and making sure things don't fall apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one piece in OOP toolset, that allows you to enforce this kind of design : constructors.

Implement handling classes, so it accepts the request class inside it's constructor. This allows you to specify more concrete version of request class, while not breaking any kind of virtual method or class polymorphism. Concrete handler will require concrete request in it's constructor, while passing it's generic form to it's predecessor.

The problem then gets shifted to how to create concrete handler for concrete type of request. You could use "downchast check" or maybe a Visitor pattern, if you want compile-time typechecking. Encapsulating it in Factory class is given. This problem I believe is the core of your concern. If you can ensure correct handler is paired with correct request, then no problems can occur. Using constructors for parameters ensures, that the handler cannot be called incorrectly outside this factory.

Comment: hmm, it worked -- big thanks! I was surprised it worked though. Aren't constructors just a methods LSP is applied to? Why constructors can be non-polymorphic?

And concerning the first part -- about hierarchy as well -- here it is: http://pastebin.com/ucya1iRH (scala) and http://pastebin.com/fJyTRVBv (php) Did I get it right?